# Internet Relay Chat rfc implementation

Tags: client-server, chat, irc

I am currently coding an Internet Relay Chat client/server implementation.
I read the RFC 1459 but some points are still unclear to me.

First let's say we have three users A, B and C.
A post a channel message, should I send it back to A, B and C or just B and C ? I mean should the client of A handle their own posting?

And the second point is, I would like to handle the possibility for the user to /join multiple channels.
How then could I handle the fact that my user can only post to one channel at a time? The RFC is unclear about it.

Regards, Swann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first sense no. Messages are not broadcast, so the user will not receive their own message back.

When sending a message you provide the destination. Whether that's a user or a channel. So `PRIVMSG #channel :hello world` will target that message to `#channel`. Other users in that room will receive the following:

```
:juco!~juco@hostname.com PRIVMSG #example :Hello world
```

This is explained in more details in [4.4.1 Private messages](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1459#section-4.4.1).

Comment: It's what I though too but [3.2.2 To a ground (channel)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1459#section-3.2.2) seems to go against your first point but other parts confirms it, very unclear.

So for example if user A writes "Hello world !" will it be replaced by
    "PRIVMSG #currentActiveChannel :Hello world !" ?"

Comment: You are right, my answer was completely incorrect. I've just telnet to a few IRC servers to validate this and have update my answer accordingly.

Comment: And what about the second part, do you confirm my thoughts ?

Comment: @SwannPolydor: It is up to the user's client to keep track of an "active channel" and send their channel messages to the right place.  As far as the server is concerned, every message from a client comes with an explicit destination (channel or user).